# Joomla 2.5: assign user to usergroup from front-end

Tags: joomla, acl, frontend, usergroups

I have statically defined user groups with statically defined access rights.
And I want to be able to change the user group for given user from the front-end using some module.

Reason: users can register by themselves, and automatically go to group "registered". After some time they can be promoted and moved to group "member". But I don't want to do this from back-end, bcs e.g. promotion can be done by any another already member. So I need this in front-end.

I haven't found any mention about this in Google. Maybe this is just something obvious? Are there any module/plugin perfoming such task?

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla core components don't allow this. But you can search on http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management if there is something that fits your needs.
Maybe this one: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/13753

Comment: You can select the usergroup you wish to assign the user to when creating a new user with the extension you mentioned, but I don't believe you can edit a current user.

Answer (score 0):

You could  make a module with a button and have the button use JUserHelper::addUserToGroup.